# What is the better way to change the percentages of the training and the testing during the splitting process?

Tags: matlab, pca

With using the PCA technique and the [Yale database](http://vision.ucsd.edu/content/yale-face-database), I'm trying to work on face recognition within Matlab by randomly splitting the training process to 20% and the testing process to 80%. It is given an

> Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 29)

error. The following is the code, hoping to get help:

```
dataset = load('yale_FaceDataset.mat');

trainSz = round(dataset.samples*0.2);
testSz = round(dataset.samples*0.8);

trainSetCell = cell(1,trainSz*dataset.classes);
testSetCell = cell(1,testSz*dataset.classes);

j = 1;
k = 1;
m = 1;
for i = 1:dataset.classes
    % training set
    trainSetCell(k:k+trainSz-1) = dataset.images(j:j+trainSz-1);
    trainLabels(k:k+trainSz-1) = dataset.labels(j:j+trainSz-1);
    k = k+trainSz;
    % test set
    testSetCell(m:m+testSz-1) = dataset.images(j+trainSz:j+dataset.samples-1);
    testLabels(m:m+testSz-1) = dataset.labels(j+trainSz:j+dataset.samples-1);
    m = m+testSz;
    j = j+dataset.samples;
end
% convert the data from a cell into a matrix format
numImgs = length(trainSetCell);
trainSet = zeros(numImgs,numel(trainSetCell{1}));
for i = 1:numImgs
    trainSet(i,:) = reshape(trainSetCell{i},[],1);
end
numImgs = length(testSetCell);

testSet = zeros(numImgs,numel(testSetCell{1}));
for i = 1:numImgs
    testSet(i,:) = reshape(testSetCell{i},[],1);
end


%% applying PCA
% compute the mean face
mu = mean(trainSet)';

% centre the training data
trainSet = trainSet - (repmat(mu,1,size(trainSet,1)))';

% generate the eigenfaces(features of the training set)
eigenfaces = pca(trainSet);

% set the number of principal components
Ncomponents = 100;

% Out of the generated components, we keep "Ncomponents"
eigenfaces = eigenfaces(:,1:Ncomponents);

% generate training features
trainFeatures = eigenfaces' * trainSet';

% Subspace projection
% centre features
testSet = testSet - (repmat(mu,1,size(testSet,1)))';

% subspace projection
testFeatures = inv(eigenfaces'*eigenfaces) * eigenfaces' * testSet';

mdl = fitcdiscr(trainFeatures',trainLabels);
labels = predict(mdl,testFeatures');


% find the images that were recognised and their respect. labels
correctRec = find(testLabels == labels');
correctLabels = labels(correctRec);

% find the images that were NOT recognised and their respect. labels
falseRec = find(testLabels ~= labels');
falseLabels = labels(falseRec);


% compute and display the recognition rate
result = length(correctRec)/length(testLabels)*100;
fprintf('The recognition rate is: %0.3f \n',result);

% divide the images into : recognised and unrecognised
correctTest = testSetCell(correctRec);
falseTest = testSetCell(falseRec);

% display some recognised samples and their respective labels
imgshow(correctTest(1:8),correctLabels(1:8));

% display all unrecognised samples and their respective labels
imgshow(falseTest(1:length(falseTest)), falseLabels(1:length(falseTest)));
```

Answer (score 1):

it would be nice, if you provide also the line-number and the full message of the error and if you would strip your code to the essential. I guess, the PCA-stuff is not necessary here, as the error is raised probably in your loop. That is because you are incrementing `j` by `j = j+dataset.samples;` and take this in the next loop-set for indexing `j:j+trainSz-1`, which now must exceed `dataset.samples`...

Nevertheless, there is no randomness in the indexing. It is easiest if you use the built-in [`cvpartition`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html)-function:

```
% split data 
cvp = cvpartition(Lbl,'HoldOut',.2);
lgTrn = cvp.training;
lgTst = cvp.test;
```

You may provide the number of classes as first input (`Lbl` in this case) or the actual class vector to let `cvpartition` pick random subsets that reflect the original distribution of the individual classes.